# JQuery: содержание текста в зависимости от слов в нем

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день, прошу помощи в решении следующего вопроса:
Есть html код выводимый динамически из бд.
К примеру -

```
<div class="newlist">
  <ul>
     <li>Тест 1</li>
     <li>Тест 2</li>
     <li>Ошибка</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как написать скрипт который при нахождении слова "Ошибка" делал какое то действие (к примеру выводил ниже строчку "В тексте ошибка!").
По сути как найти слово с помошью

```
.find(:contains('Ошибка'))
```

я понял, а вот делать выборку if else , никак не получается. Заранее спасибо !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

```
if ($(":contains('Ошибка')").length > 0)
{
   console.log("Нашли ошибку");
}
```

т.е. если количество найденных объектов больше нуля.

Comment: Огромное спасибо !, все время забывал про условие.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YW3eR/

по-моему, все работает - Если нашли 'is' в тексте у id=red то изменим у элемента с id=green text-decoration на подчеркнутый

Comment: Странно в фиддле все работает ... Прошу прощения, еще раз благодарю за ответ.